# No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://com.springbootsoap.allapis}addProductRequest]

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, soapui, endpoint

```
I have been having issues trying to get endpoint mapping to work for my web service. I am using Tomcat to host my web service and I am using soapUI to send test messages to it.
```

## Endpoint

```
@Endpoint
public class ProductEndpoint {
    
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URL="http://com.springbootsoap.allapis";
    
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;
    
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URL, localPart = "addProductRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public AddProductResponse addProduct(@RequestPayload AddProductRequest request) {
        
        AddProductResponse response= new AddProductResponse();
        ServiceStatus servicestatus=new ServiceStatus();
        
        Product product=new Product();
        
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(request.getProductInfo(),product);
        productService.addProduct(product);
        servicestatus.setStatus("Success");
        servicestatus.setMessage("Content Added Successfully");
        response.setServiceStatus(servicestatus);
        return response;
    }
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URL, localPart = "getProductByIdRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetProductResponse GetProduct(@RequestPayload GetProductByIdRequest request) {
        GetProductResponse response=new GetProductResponse();
        ProductInfo productInfo=new ProductInfo();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(productService.getProductById(request.getProductId()),productInfo);
        response.setProductInfo(productInfo);
        
        return response;
        
    }
}
```

### SoapUI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhnUE.png)

here is what I got in soapUi.

I do not have any idea what should I do to make it correct, I saw many questions regarding this problem but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same issue. At that time I change the version of java to 1.8 in pom.xml file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).